# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' How can I install packages in python folders? rather than in anaconda

Tags: opencv, module, pip, anaconda, python-idle

I have previously installed python 3.7, anaconda3 and jupyter notebook.
Then I tried to install opencv library using the following command.

`pip install opencv-python`

and it said,

> Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.1.1.26)

When I tried to import open-cv library from IDLE it gives the following error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'.

But when I run it from the jupyter notebook it works.

The reason for this as I see is that the packages are installed in the anaconda3 folders but not in the python folders.

How can I install packages in python folders? As I need to run this from the IDLE.

I'm using python 3.7.1 on windows 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

what IDLE are u using for program in python? If you are using Python IDLE, usually when you import packages, are installed in **C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib**

If you want to install a package in other folder, try to use this

`pip install --target=C:\path\to\folder\ opencv-python`

If you have another IDLE, put me in the comments what is it **(PyCharm, VSCode...).**

Comment: I'm seeing that you are using **Anaconda.** When you install Anaconda, it should include a **Anaconda prompt.** Try to put ```pip install opencv-python``` in the Anaconda Prompt

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked using pip target folder

Comment: Nice to help you :)